# Iam using python but i can not handel detect QR code using openCV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, opencv

I am not able to detect the QR code in registration certificate image

```py
# import the necessary packages
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
from pyzbar import pyzbar
image = cv2.imread("myimages/adhar1.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# compute the Scharr gradient magnitude representation of the images
# in both the x and y direction using OpenCV 2.4
ddepth = cv2.cv.CV_32F if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.CV_32F
gradX = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=ddepth, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
gradY = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=ddepth, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=-1)

# subtract the y-gradient from the x-gradient
gradient = cv2.subtract(gradX, gradY)
gradient = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gradient)
cv2.imshow("gradient", gradient)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# blur and threshold the image
blurred = cv2.blur(gradient, (3, 3))
cv2.imshow("blurred", blurred)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
(_, thresh) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# construct a closing kernel and apply it to the thresholded image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# perform a series of erosions and dilations
closed = cv2.erode(closed, None, iterations=4)
closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations=4)
cv2.imshow("Image22.jpg", closed)
cv2.waitKey()

#find the contours in the thresholded image, then sort the contours
# by their area, keeping only the largest one
cnts = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[0]

# compute the rotated bounding box of the largest contour
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
# print(box)

# draw a bounding box arounded the detected barcode and display the
order_points = image[box[1][1]:box[3][1],box[1][0]:box[3][0]]
cv2.imwrite("test.jpg", order_points)
barcode = pyzbar.decode(order_points)
print(barcode)
cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
# cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Image1.jpg", image)
barcoad = pyzbar.decode(image)
print(barcoad)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Hear am using open-CV for Barbados image detection but am not able to find registration certificate(rc). Please give me a better solution for thin problem.

Comment: Kindly clean up your question removing the unnecessary paragraph you added. If you want to create a tag or a tag synonym and don't have enough rep to do so, please ask in the meta.

Comment: @MerajalMaksud Actually, the text seems to come from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368537/11089932), and was most likely put in the question to bypass the minimum amount of actual text in relation to given codes. I removed that paragraph.